# Laptop internal speaker beeps at startup if laptop plugged in

Tags: lenovo-laptop

When my laptop is booting, if it is plugged in, the internal speaker keeps beeping. Not continually, it's more of a *beep* *beep* thing but never stops.

What could be the cause of it? How can I troubleshoot and pinpoint the error?

Comment: Please [edit] and post a question.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Yeah, sorry about that

Comment: Make / model of laptop? Age? Always been like this or started recently? What changed if the latter? Battery tested / charging ok / holding a charge? BIOS updates applied? Different power adapter tried? Different battery tried?

Comment: These beeps are generally [specific to a BIOS](https://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm) and telling you about issues with hardware during startup. Along with what Appleoddity says try checking the [Device Manager](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager) for problems.